# Get number of items in carousel - ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net

In no way I am an ASP.net developer, however I was put to sort out an issue with a carousel appearing on a page, even taken that there are no slides to display. I've opened the code I've found from the previous developer and found this part (shortened):

```
@if (new SchoolWebber.Models.SiteViewModel().DisplayCarouselOnAllPages || ViewBag.IsHomePage != null) {

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">

    @{ var imagecounter = 0;} @foreach (var item in new SchoolWebber.Models.SiteViewModel().GetCarousel()) { if (imagecounter == 0) {
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@imagecounter" class="active"></li>
    } else {
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@imagecounter"></li>
    } imagecounter++; }
  </ol>

  ....

}
```

So, if I got it right, it checks if the carousel is set to be displayed on all pages, otherwise it shows it on the *homepage*. However, the problem is that it shows the carousel on the homepage, even taken that there are no items to display.

How do I apply here a condition that would count the number of items inside SchoolWebber.Models.SiteViewModel().GetCarousel() and show the carousel only if that number is greater than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using System.Linq  @* place it in the top of file *@

// ... rest of your code

@{ var carouselModel = new SchoolWebber.Models.SiteViewModel().GetCarousel(); }
@if (carouselModel.Any() &&
     (new SchoolWebber.Models.SiteViewModel().DisplayCarouselOnAllPages || ViewBag.IsHomePage != null)) 
{

    // ... rest of your code

    @{ var imagecounter = 0;} 
    @foreach (var item in carouselModel)

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it now.